# Write this piecewise function in terms of the unit step

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

\begin{align}
f(t) = \begin{cases} 3t &\mbox{if } t \leq 3 \\
12 & \mbox{if } 3<t\leq 7 \\
0 & \mbox{if } t\geq 7 \end{cases} 
\end{align}

I'm confused as to how I can write this in terms of the unit step function with the first f(t) has $\leq 3$ instead of just $\lt 3$.  Any help with this problem?

Comment: I edited your latex, please check if this is still consistent

Comment: This is besides the question, but your function is slightly flawed. At $t=7$, is $f(t)$ equal to 12 or 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the definition of the Heaviside function - it can be either 0, 1 or 0.5 at H(0).

If you take it to be zero, I think the following works:

[3tH(3-t) + 12 H(7-t) H(t-3)]H(7-t)

Comment: Indeed, http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B3t+H%283-t%29+%2B+12+H%287-t%29+H%28t-3%29%5DH%287-t%29